# E: Failure running hook [ ! -f /usr/bin/snap ]

Tags: snap, nextcloud

Greetings Ubuntu community!

I'm running an older version of Ubuntu 16.04 that I setup a little while back so I could run my own personal Nextcloud server. I've tried researching the snap error I'm getting using multiple search terms provided by the verbose with no luck so I figured I would come here. It seems like a link problem with snap is causing an error to be thrown. Whenever I try to use for example `sudo apt upgrade`, `sudo apt install <package>` etc it gives me this error:

```
sudo apt install openssh-server
[sudo] password for sysadmin:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required: 
  libicu64 libllvm7 libllvm8
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  ncurses-term openssh-sftp-server ssh-import-id
Suggested packages:
  molly-guard monkeysphere rssh ssh-askpass
E: Waited for [ ! -f /usr/bin/snap ] || /usr/bin/snap advise-snap --from-apt 2>/dev/null || true but it wasn't there
E: Failure running hook [ ! -f /usr/bin/snap ] || /usr/bin/snap advise-snap --from-apt 2>/dev/null || true
E: Waited for [ ! -f /usr/bin/snap ] || /usr/bin/snap advise-snap --from-apt 2>/dev/null || true but it wasn't there
E: Failure running hook [ ! -f /usr/bin/snap ] || /usr/bin/snap advise-snap --from-apt 2>/dev/null || true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message looks strange, but we can overcome it by creating a temporary replacement for `/usr/bin/snap`:

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /usr/bin/snap
#!/bin/bash
exit 0
EOF

sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/snap
```

then install your application with `sudo apt install openssh-server`.

And finally reinstall Snap daemon to replace our temporary script:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall snapd
```

Comment: That seems to have fixed it, thank you N0rbert for your clear, clean answer to something I had spent a day looking around for. I'm not familiar with snap so I figured it looked like a link problem but seeing as this is my personal cloud server I was hesitant to do anything without outside advice.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you actually intended to remove `snapd`, you could also remove the buggy APT hook that causes this error when it is uninstalled:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20snapd.conf
```